Slight Misalignment Issue on Stitching Images Together in Grid-Like Manner
Slight Misalignment Issue on Stitching Images Together in Grid-Like Manner
I am trying to create high res composite images of rugs, with all parts in focus. For this the best approach I figured out was to take several shots of different parts of the rug and then stitch them together.
I was initially doing this with Photoshop API, but very recently (within past 30 days) Adobe has bundled Photoshop API into Firefly which is currently enterprise only. So now I am trying to create a OpenCV function for the same.
My original images are:-



Top to bottom (Image 5, 3, 1)
Top to bottom (Image 6, 4, 2)




  Image 5
  Image 6


  Image 3
  Image 4


  Image 1
  Image 2



High Resolution versions of these images are available here
I tried doing this with stitcher class of Open CV, even played around with several parameters but they seem to work with some sets of images, and not with all. So currently doing this manual approach.
Current Approach
I am doing pairwise stitching.
So in first iteration I will stitch the rows together
1 gets stitched with 2
3 gets stiched with 4
5 gets stitched with 6



Results are decent




  Row 1


  Row 2


  Row 3



I am able to do blending and exposure compensation for seamless results, so we can ignore them in these test images.
Next step is I stitch row 1 with row 2, to result and then stitch those results with row 3 to get the final composite. The results are :-



Final Results




  Row 1 & 2


  Above stitched with Row 3



I have not cropped the images to maintain trueness, so please excuse the additional white parts in the stitched images.
Problem
If you look at the final image, it has slight misalignments at the edges of the rug. This is what i am unable to remove.
My code is
import cv2
from loader import load_images
from stitcher import stitch_images_manual

def main():
    corrected_images_dir = "out"
    num_images = 6  # Adjust this to the number of images you have
    rows = 3  # Number of rows in your grid
    columns = 2  # Number of columns in your grid

    # Load images
    images = load_images(corrected_images_dir, num_images)
    if len(images) == 0:
        print("No images loaded.")
        return

    # Stitch images in pairs for each row
    row_images = []
    for i in range(rows):
        start_idx = i * columns
        pair = [images[start_idx], images[start_idx + 1]]
        print(f'Stitching row {i + 1} with images {start_idx + 1} and {start_idx + 2}')
        stitched_row = stitch_images_manual(pair[0], pair[1])
        if stitched_row is not None:
            row_images.append(stitched_row)
            cv2.imwrite(f'out/stitched_row_{i + 1}.png', stitched_row)
            print(f'Saved stitched row {i + 1} as stitched_row_{i + 1}.png')
        else:
            print(f'Stitching failed for row {i + 1}')
            return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


import cv2
import numpy as np
from features import detect_and_compute_features
from homography import compute_homography
from warp import warp_image
from resize import resize_image
from camera_params import estimate_initial_camera_params, refine_camera_params

def stitch_images_manual(image1, image2, scale_percent=50):
    print(f"Stitching images of shapes: {image1.shape} and {image2.shape}")

    # # Resize images to medium resolution
    # image1_resized = resize_image(image1, scale_percent)
    # image2_resized = resize_image(image2, scale_percent)

    # Convert images to grayscale
    gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
    gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)

    # Detect SIFT features and compute descriptors
    keypoints1, descriptors1 = detect_and_compute_features(gray1)
    keypoints2, descriptors2 = detect_and_compute_features(gray2)

    # Match features using FLANN matcher
    FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
    index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=10)
    search_params = dict(checks=500)
    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
    matches = flann.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, k=2)

    # Apply ratio test
    good_matches = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
            good_matches.append(m)

    if len(good_matches) < 4:
        print("Not enough good matches to compute homography.")
        return None

    # Extract location of good matches
    points1 = np.zeros((len(good_matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
    points2 = np.zeros((len(good_matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

    for i, match in enumerate(good_matches):
        points1[i, :] = keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt
        points2[i, :] = keypoints2[match.trainIdx].pt

    # Compute homography
    h = compute_homography(points1, points2)

    if h is None:
        return None

    # Get dimensions of input images
    height1, width1 = image1.shape[:2]
    height2, width2 = image2.shape[:2]

    # Determine canvas size based on stitching direction
    if height1 > height2:
        canvas_width = max(width1, width2)
        canvas_height = height1 + height2
    else:
        canvas_width = width1 + width2
        canvas_height = max(height1, height2)

    # Warp the second image to the first image's plane
    warped_image2 = warp_image(image2, h, (canvas_width, canvas_height))

    # Create the stitched image canvas
    result = np.zeros((canvas_height, canvas_width, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
    result[0:height1, 0:width1] = image1

    # Create a mask of where the warped image has valid pixels
    mask = np.any(warped_image2 != 0, axis=2)

    # Paste the warped image pixels into the result image
    result[mask] = warped_image2[mask]

    return result

import cv2
import numpy as np

def warp_image(image, homography, canvas_size):
    warped_image = cv2.warpPerspective(image, homography, canvas_size)
    # cv2.imshow("warped",warped_image)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)
    # cv2.destroyAllWindows
    return warped_image


import os
import cv2

def load_images(image_dir, num_images):
    images = []
    for i in range(1, num_images + 1):
        image_path = os.path.join(image_dir, f'{i}.png')
        if os.path.exists(image_path):
            img = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
            if img.shape[2] == 3:
                img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
            images.append(img)
            print(f'Loaded image {i} with shape {img.shape}')
        else:
            print(f'Image {image_path} not found.')
    return images


import cv2
import numpy as np

def compute_homography(points1, points2):
    h, mask = cv2.findHomography(points2, points1, cv2.RANSAC)
    if h is None:
        print("Homography computation failed.")

    return h

import cv2

def detect_and_compute_features(image):
    sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
    keypoints, descriptors = sift.detectAndCompute(image, None)
    return keypoints, descriptors


Currently, I manually stitch the rows first, then rotate the results and feed them again by changing the rows parameter. This is just lazy working on my part and easily resolvable so please ignore this as well.
Any ideas on what can I do to improve the results? I tried stitching images after removing background but even that doesn't work.
Any tips or pointers that could guide me in the right direction would be much appreciated.
I have tried several packages for stitching from github but all give similar misaligned results.

For the homography to be accurate, the camera's position (i.e., the optical center) must remain constant. This is because the homography is derived under the assumption that the transformation between the images is purely due to a change in the camera's orientation (rotation), and not its position (translation).

Thank you for your response @LukasWeber. So is bundle adjustment the solution? I read somewhere that Open CVs built in bundle adjustment function doesn't take into account translations. So should a 3rd party like ceres solver or Colomap be used in this case? I don't have camera intrinsic parameters , just focal length and camera sensor size, will this suffice ?

Can you just take the pictures while holding the camera still?

No, have to move around to capture different parts of the rug so movement will be there along all 3 axis

You can just try standing before the carpet, hold the camera still and just rotate it to take the pictures. Maybe the result is enough

I see no reason to exclude translation. in plane-to-plane mapping, a homography allows for translation. -- remember, this isn't a 360 panorama. this is supposed to result in a stitched ground plane.

@ChristophRackwitz do you mean plane-to-plane mapping as in affine stitching?

if the carpet lies flat on the ground, the surface to be textured is a plane. it is not a sphere. homography is appropriate for composing pictures of the carpet into one big texture of it. there is no serious restriction on the positions of the views. I would recommend starting with a wide shot capturing the entire carpet. that gives the detail shots an absolute reference.

affine mapping would require the absence of perspective. that's only the case for flatbed scans. OpenCV appears to have a "hole" in its modeling. it either assumes flatbed scans (plane, translations, no perspectives), or a panorama (sphere, no translation, perspectives). there is no model for a plane with translated perspective views. not that I can tell from the docs, but who knows, maybe there is. I am fairly unfamiliar with that module.

Thanks for clarification! The warper has support for "full_affine (two more DoF)", I always wondered what could be a use case for that. Do you think the given problem might be a use case for that?

6 dof over 4 dof likely describes stretching (two-axis scaling) and shearing/skewing. that won't help with perspective.

What might be missing is correcting for lens distortion.

@CrisLuengo I don't have the lens distortion values, only focal length and sensor size.

You can measure the lens distortion. OpenCV has the utilities for that I believe. You need to take an image of a chessboard pattern and feed it into the right function. Then you have the parameters to correct each image produced by that lens (as long as you're using the same zoom setting, for zoom lenses).

As a summary of the discussion in the comments: OpenCVs stitching module supports at least two ways of taking Images
panorama (sphere, no translation, perspectives)

flatbed scans (plane, translations, no perspectives)

Your use case doesn't fit in one of the two. However, as Christoph Rackwitz pointed out:

if the carpet lies flat on the ground, the surface to be textured is a
plane. it is not a sphere. homography is appropriate for composing
pictures of the carpet into one big texture of it.

and indeed, OpenCV is capable of estimating a homography for your Images.
OpenCV offers different warpers for homography ( see stitching_detailed.py or the stitching package). You might get better results with the plane warper

Thanks, I tried the plane and other warpers, but the resulting image is misaligned.

Ok, then its probably just not supported yet

you can always DIY with explicit feature matching and warpPerspective() calls. be careful, most people seem to follow some junk tutorials that do this wrong.

Ah now I think I understand what you've ment with 'I would recommend starting with a wide shot capturing the entire carpet. that gives the detail shots an absolute reference'. So you warp the high detail shots onto the base image?

@ChristophRackwitz I am also following a bunch of "junk" tutorials. Would you know of any good resources that can properly guide me through this?

the main point is to not warp the image recursively. if you do that, it turns blurry.

More than blurriness my issue is that say if there will be slight misalignment at the edge of 1 image with another... misalignments are usually limited to 1 -2 instances only when composing with 6/8 images..
There should be a way to fine tune it, but I am unable to figure out how..
